# How do I optimize this code so that it executes faster (max ~5 mins)?

Tags: python-turtle

I am trying to make a program in turtle that creates a Lyapunov fractal. However, as using timeit shows, this should take around 3 hours to complete, 1.5 if I compromise resolution (N).

```
import turtle as t; from math import log; from timeit import default_timer as dt
t.setup(2000,1000,0); swid=t.window_width(); shei=t.window_height(); t.up(); t.ht(); t.tracer(False); t.colormode(255); t.bgcolor('pink')

def lyapunov(seq,xmin,xmax,ymin,ymax,N,tico):
    truseq=str(bin(seq))[2:]
    for x in range(-swid//2+2,swid//2-2):
        tx=(x*(xmax-xmin))/swid+(xmax+xmin)/2
        if x==-swid//2+2:
            startt=dt()
        for y in range(-shei//2+11,shei//2-1):
            t.goto(x,y); ty=(y*(ymax-ymin))/shei+(ymax+ymin)/2; lex=0; xn=prevxn=0.5
            for n in range(1,N+1):
                if truseq[n%len(truseq)]=='0': rn=tx
                else: rn=ty
                xn=rn*prevxn*(1-prevxn)
                prevxn=xn
                if xn!=1: lex+=(1/N)*log(abs(rn*(1-2*xn)))
            if lex>0: t.pencolor(0,0,min(int(lex*tico),255))
            else: t.pencolor(max(255+int(lex*tico),0),max(255+int(lex*tico),0),0)
            t.dot(size=1); t.update()
        if x==-swid//2+2:
            endt=dt()
            print(f'Estimated total time: {(endt-startt)*(swid-5)} secs')

#Example: lyapunov(2,2.0,4.0,2.0,4.0,10000,100)
```

I attempted to use yield but I couldn't figure out where it should go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On my slower machine, I was only able to test with a tiny N (e.g. 10) but I was able to speed up the code about 350 times.  (Though this will be clearly lower as N increases.)  There are two problems with your use of `update()`.  The first is you call it too often -- you should outdent it from the `y` loop to the `x` loop so it's only called once on each vertical pass.  Second, the `dot()` operator forces an automatic `update()` so you get no advantage from using `tracer()`.  Replace `dot()` with some other method of drawing a pixel and you'll get back the advantage of using `tracer()` and `update()`.  (As long as you move `update()` out of innermost loop as I noted.)

My rework of your code where I tried out these, and other, changes:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle
from math import log
from timeit import default_timer

def lyapunov(seq, xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax, N, tico):
    xdif = xmax - xmin
    ydif = ymax - ymin

    truseq = str(bin(seq))[2:]

    for x in range(2 - swid_2, swid_2 - 2):
        if x == 2 - swid_2:
            startt = default_timer()

        tx = x * xdif / swid + xdif/2

        for y in range(11 - shei_2, shei_2 - 1):
            ty = y * ydif / shei + ydif/2
            lex = 0
            xn = prevxn = 0.5

            for n in range(1, N+1):
                rn = tx if truseq[n % len(truseq)] == '0' else ty

                xn = rn * prevxn * (1 - prevxn)
                prevxn = xn

                if xn != 1:
                    lex += 1/N * log(abs(rn * (1 - xn*2)))

            if lex > 0:
                turtle.pencolor(0, 0, min(int(lex * tico), 255))
            else:
                lex_tico = max(int(lex * tico) + 255, 0)
                turtle.pencolor(lex_tico, lex_tico, 0)

            turtle.goto(x, y)
            turtle.pendown()

        turtle.penup()
        screen.update()

        if x == 2 - swid_2:
            endt = default_timer()
            print(f'Estimated total time: {(endt - startt) * (swid - 5)} secs')

screen = Screen()
screen.setup(2000, 1000, startx=0)
screen.bgcolor('pink')
screen.colormode(255)
screen.tracer(False)

swid = screen.window_width()
shei = screen.window_height()

swid_2 = swid//2
shei_2 = shei//2

turtle = Turtle()
turtle.hideturtle()
turtle.penup()
turtle.setheading(90)

lyapunov(2, 2.0, 4.0, 2.0, 4.0, 10, 100)

screen.exitonclick()
```